# JGit fetch() don't update tag

Tags: jgit

My remote repository got a tag moved to a new commit.
I run:

```java
git.fetch().setTagOpt(TagOpt.FETCH_TAGS)
   .setRemote("remoteURL")
   .setRefSpecs(new RefSpec("+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"))
   .call();
```

`FetchResult` includes a `REJECTED` update. 
The equivalent cli `git -t ...` does not behave this way.

Don't want to argue cli vs JGit, but wonder how I can do a fetch to update tags?

Seems I have to get `org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.RefUpdate` with `force=true`, but don't know how... and don't realy want to duplicate all FetchProcess code :'(

Answer (score 2):

This was a known problem that was fixed in JGit 3.0, see [bug 388095](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388095).

As for a solution that works with the earlier releases, adding an explicit refspec for tags helps:

```
+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```